# getElementById returns 0 in (jest) testing, but works fine in browser

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I've built my first app with `create-react-app` , and I'm trying to include a simple test.
Somehow the test always returns `TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of null` even though the code works in the browser and the app works exactly as expected.

Here is my **test.js**:

```
import computeFib from '../Fib_Calc';

describe("Fib Function", () => {

    test('Fib result is undefined on negative input', () => {
        const input = -5;
        const output = 'undefined';
        expect(computeFib(input)).toEqual(output);
    })
```

**Fib_Calc.js**:

```
function clearResult() {
    var results = document.getElementById("results");
    results.innerHTML = '';
    return null;
}

function createErrorMsg(msg) {
    var label = document.getElementById('label');
    var error = document.createElement('div');
    error.id = 'error_message';
    error.innerHTML = msg;
    document.getElementById("fib_nr").classList.add("input_error"); //line that throws error message
    label.appendChild(error);
}

const computeFib = n => {

    if (n < 0) {
        let msg = 'Please choose a positive value.';
        createErrorMsg(msg);
        clearResult();
    }

    else if (n < 2) {
        return n;
    }

    else {
        return computeFib(n - 1) + computeFib(n - 2);
    }
}

export default computeFib;
```

The element in question that throws the arrow comes from my **Form.js**:

```
< form className="form" id="form" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                <label htmlFor="fib_nr" id="label">Choose a position in the Fib sequence:
                    <input
                        type="number"
                        id="fib_nr" //id is specified and works in browser
                        name="fib_nr"
                        required="required"
                        min="0"
                        step="1"
                        onInvalid={this.handleSubmit}
                        value={this.state.value}
                        onChange={this.handleChange}
                        placeholder="Choose a number." />
                </label>
...
```

I tried to console log `document.getElementById("fib_nr")` this returns 0 in the test environment and the input element in the browser.

For the fun of it, I also tried to console log `document.getElementById("label")` (a few lines above where the error throws) and this *also* logs to 0 in the test environment.

As I'm a react newbie, I would appreciate some a detailed responses. I've thought about adding a windows load function to the test, but wasn't quit sure how to do it.

Also should mention that I had problems with the same piece of code before in the app / browser and that was solved by adding the `defer` tag to all `<script>` elements.

Comment: You appear to only be testing the `computeFib` function, which doesn't render any JSX. If you are trying to test a React component then you need to render the component into *some* test wrapper (see Enzyme or React-Testing-Library). You also appear to implement React anti-patterns, like direct DOM manipulations. These should be avoided.

Comment: Really, you shouldn't be using the DOM directly when using a library like React. You should be changing state, and React -- well, reacts, to the change in state by adjusting the DOM. So your `createErrorMsg` would set a `hasError` property to true, say, and an `errorMessage` property to `msg`, etc. Then you would have code that, based on those two pieces of state, would generate the appropriate HTML and set the appropriate values and attributes.

Comment: Ok, so what you're both saying is, is that I shouldn't use getElementById at all?

Comment: Sort of... the React way to access DOMNodes is to use a React ref attached to the element, but the bigger issue is more about the setting of innerHTML. This counts as DOM manipulation. You should handle the text and state in React and render the content you want. This doesn't fix your test though, you still need to render ***a*** component that is rendering this JSX. A test for `computeFib` function is fine, but the DOM mutations should be removed and a React component should be handling it.

Comment: ok, thank you - I will take another look at these concepts.